# Kolgomorov entropy issues

Tags: specific-reference, entropy, complex-systems

I am long been confused by these entropy terms. Would be  obliged if an explanation is provided in less technical jargon

1. What are the differences between Shannon's entropy, topological entropy and source entropy?
2. What exactly is the significane of Kolgomorov complexity. Is it same as Kolgomorov entropy. How is it related to Shannon's entropy?
3. What information does the complexity number convey? It is known that source entropy=kolgomorov entropy , so what does this imply from the point of view of infomation theory?

Thank you

Comment: what is "source entropy"? It doesn't google for me. Is it just another name for Kolmogorov entropy?

Comment: maybe you could break this question into several questions?  Some people might only be able to answer one of your questions and those don't feel it's appropriate to answer this thread.